# Android Google Maps V2 in Fragment

Tags: android, google-maps

I am creating an app in android 17 and I am trying to include Google Maps v2.

In my current set-up I have an ActionBar with two tabs, one pointing to travel information and one pointing to Google Maps.

I can get Google maps to display in the main activity, but I can't get the map to display in a fragment.

Here is my Maps Class code:

```
// Will hold the information for the "Maps" tab
public class Maps extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.rowlayout);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Venue Map

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        RelativeLayout layoutView = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.action_bar_tab, null);
        TextView tabText = (TextView) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.tabText);
        ImageView tabImage = (ImageView) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.tabImage);

        String venueMapTab = "Travel Information";
        Tab tab = actionBar.newTab();
        TabListener<VenueMap> dayOne = new TabListener<VenueMap>(this,
                venueMapTab, VenueMap.class);
        tab.setTabListener(dayOne); 
        tabText.setText("Venue Map");
        tab.setCustomView(layoutView);
        actionBar.addTab(tab);

        // Google Maps

        RelativeLayout layoutViewMaps = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.action_bar_tab, null);
        tabText = (TextView) layoutViewMaps.findViewById(R.id.tabText);
        tabImage = (ImageView) layoutViewMaps.findViewById(R.id.tabImage);

        String googleMapsTab = "Google Maps";
        tab = actionBar.newTab();
        TabListener<GoogleMaps> dayTwo = new TabListener<GoogleMaps>(this,
                googleMapsTab, GoogleMaps.class);
        tab.setTabListener(dayTwo);
        tabText.setText("Google Maps");
        tab.setCustomView(layoutViewMaps);
        actionBar.addTab(tab);

    }
```

Here is my Google Maps fragment

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.google_maps);
}
```

And the google_maps.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

And my log cat error:

```
01-28 13:44:09.830: E/AndroidRuntime(22253): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-28 13:44:09.830: E/AndroidRuntime(22253): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.zshare.blog/com.zshare.blog.Maps}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
01-28 13:44:09.830: E/AndroidRuntime(22253):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
01-28 13:44:09.830: E/AndroidRuntime(22253):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-28 13:44:09.830: E/AndroidRuntime(22253):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-28 13:44:09.830: E/AndroidRuntime(22253):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-28 13:44:09.830: E/AndroidRuntime(22253):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-28 13:44:09.830: E/AndroidRuntime(22253):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-28 13:44:09.830: E/AndroidRuntime(22253):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-28 13:44:09.830: E/AndroidRuntime(22253):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-28 13:44:09.830: E/AndroidRuntime(22253):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-28 13:44:09.830: E/AndroidRuntime(22253):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-28 13:44:09.830: E/AndroidRuntime(22253):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-28 13:44:09.830: E/AndroidRuntime(22253):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-28 13:44:09.830: E/AndroidRuntime(22253): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
01-28 13:44:09.830: E/AndroidRuntime(22253):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
01-28 13:44:09.830: E/AndroidRuntime(22253):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
01-28 13:44:09.830: E/AndroidRuntime(22253):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-28 13:44:09.830: E/AndroidRuntime(22253):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
01-28 13:44:09.830: E/AndroidRuntime(22253):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
01-28 13:44:09.830: E/AndroidRuntime(22253):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
01-28 13:44:09.830: E/AndroidRuntime(22253):    at com.zshare.blog..VenueMap.onActivityCreated(VenueMap.java:32)
01-28 13:44:09.830: E/AndroidRuntime(22253):    at android.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1703)
01-28 13:44:09.830: E/AndroidRuntime(22253):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:903)
01-28 13:44:09.830: E/AndroidRuntime(22253):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
01-28 13:44:09.830: E/AndroidRuntime(22253):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4736)
01-28 13:44:09.830: E/AndroidRuntime(22253):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
01-28 13:44:09.830: E/AndroidRuntime(22253):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
01-28 13:44:09.830: E/AndroidRuntime(22253):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-28 13:44:09.830: E/AndroidRuntime(22253):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
01-28 13:44:09.830: E/AndroidRuntime(22253):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
01-28 13:44:09.830: E/AndroidRuntime(22253):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
01-28 13:44:09.830: E/AndroidRuntime(22253):    at com.zshare.blog.VenueMap.onActivityCreated(VenueMap.java:32)
01-28 13:44:09.830: E/AndroidRuntime(22253):    at android.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1703)
01-28 13:44:09.830: E/AndroidRuntime(22253):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:903)
01-28 13:44:09.830: E/AndroidRuntime(22253):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
01-28 13:44:09.830: E/AndroidRuntime(22253):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
01-28 13:44:09.830: E/AndroidRuntime(22253):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
01-28 13:44:09.830: E/AndroidRuntime(22253):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5113)
01-28 13:44:09.830: E/AndroidRuntime(22253):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2153)
01-28 13:44:09.830: E/AndroidRuntime(22253):    ... 11 more
01-28 13:44:09.830: E/AndroidRuntime(22253): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #2: Duplicate id 0x7f05003b, tag null, or parent id 0x1020002 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
01-28 13:44:09.830: E/AndroidRuntime(22253):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4722)
01-28 13:44:09.830: E/AndroidRuntime(22253):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
01-28 13:44:09.830: E/AndroidRuntime(22253):    ... 35 more
```

If i display the map in an activity it works, but in a fragment I am getting an error. Any help solving this problem would be appreciated :)

Comment: You might consider editing your question to include the layout resource that is causing your crash.

Comment: Completely forgot to add it, included now :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `onActivityCreated()` is a method on `Fragment`, it would appear that you are trying to have a fragment load a fragment, which, while possible using the Android Support Library, is not going to work with the native fragments that you are using. It is also unclear why you are doing this in the first place.

Your "Google Maps fragment" either should *be* `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment` or should *inherit from* `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment`, but it should not be some separate fragment that tries to *load* `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, solved :) I shall vote up when I have enough rep.